# How can I automate a new linux server's initial setup?

Tags: ubuntu, security, automation, configuration-management

Every time I setup a new server, I follow a series of steps on each server in order to get updates, set passwd, remove login via root user, customize a familiar environment (bashrc) and secure the server.

Is it possible to do all that using a script? The setup could include:

1. distro upgrades and updates

   apt-get update

   apt-get upgrade
2. adding users

   adduser deployer

   adduser deployer sudo

   mkdir /home/deployer/.ssh

   chmod 700 /home/deployer/.ssh

   touch /home/deployer/.ssh/authorization_keys

   deployer passwd

   su deployer

   cd to /home/deployer/.ssh/

   sudo chown deployer .ssh/
3. Executing commands on local machine:

   ssh-copy-id root@hostname.com

   ssh-copy-id deployer@hostname.com
4. logging back onto server:

   chmod 400 /home/deployer/.ssh/authorized_keys

   chown deployer:deployer /home/deployer -R

5..6...7.. Customizing bashrc, editing sshd_config, installing ufw & logwatch

Comment: Look up config management systems like puppet or chef.

Comment: Or Ansible/Salt, for a different approach.

Comment: have a look at kickstart installation - https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a Kickstart or equivalent process to manage the build. Use a configuration management product like Puppet to deploy your settings.

You can also use a little bit of scripting magic to kick off the configuration management at the end of your build to make it a seamless experience.

My script sets a static IP, configures OSSEC and performs a couple puppet runs to sort out all the dependencies then runs a yum update (I'm primarily a CentOS user).

It's possible to cobble together other methods of getting the same results but I've found this  to be the most flexible method I've worked with.

Comment: Cobbler all the things!

Comment: @ScottPack - yeah, I looked Cobbler a while ago. I already Puppet, Kickstart and PXEBoot running for other things. Didn't see a reason to change. Didn't want to comment on a package I don't actively use.

Comment: Yeah, cobbler is nice, but really all it does is templatize your kickstarts so they can be programmatically built on the fly. Not much different from the erb templates in puppet.

Answer (score 2):

Kickstart/Jumpstart, [Chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) (including chef-solo), [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), [Salt](http://saltstack.com/), shell-scripts, and higher-level scripting languages can all be used to solve this problem.

Honestly, it looks like you have a decent beginnings of a shell script.  Start there, and if complexity ramps up, either iterate or look into a beefier product.  Personally I've had good experience with Chef.

The key to automating all-the-things is to start small; you don't have to go whole-hog into automation.  Pick one pain-point, and make that better.  Pick another, repeat.